# Angular Universal: Host application on multiple sub-domains or entirely different domains

Tags: angular, subdomain, angular-routing, angular-universal

I am looking to create a web-app with Angular Universal (NOT Plain Angular, since I need SSR). I tried researching but cannot find a concreate answer to how we can host single codebase to various sub-domains and make it work slightly different on each one conditionally.

E.g. Let's say there are 3 sub-domains on which app is to be hosted for now.

[www.app.com](http://www.app.com)            -  main sub-domain

markeeting.app.com     -  will have to load different sets of routes in app-routing.module.ts

xyz.app.com            -  Same routing as main with different theme and maybe some functionalities
will be hidden (Consider this a tenant sub-domain)

I know in angular we might be able to directly use the window object to fetch the URL and bootstrap the app accordingly, but I am not sure how we can achieve this using angular universal. Of course for all 3 or more sub-domains I'll have to write some manual code, I am aware about that part. I just need the URL from which the app is being called before it is bootstrapped to add the conditions and set value to some flags.

Comment: Javascript navigation doesn't work outside domains/subdomains. If a website would want to navigate to a subdomain, the page needs to be reloaded. Thus angular doesn't/cannot support this scenario

Comment: What you can do however is deploy your app once, point all subdomains to this folder, and in angular use `window.location.host` to distinguish what components you need to show. During SSR you'll have to pass the hostname from the backend through  to your angular app